# Launch and play video with python in vlc

Tags: python, vlc

I need to play a video in the vlc player on ubuntu, here's the code

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('SomethingFromNothing.mkv')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

The problem is that it just execute and do nothing after

Comment: Indeed it's a duplicate, but of this one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272532/python-vlc-wont-start-the-player thank youu